# Java : PriorityQueue queue results and natural ordering

Tags: java, collections, queue

I know, queue follow **FIFO**(First in first out) order, but I am not sure why the following output appears with below java sample program

**JAVA Sample**

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
            Queue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
            q.add("3");
            q.add("1");
            q.add("2");

            Iterator<String> itr = q.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(itr.next() + "    ");
            }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
1    
3    
2
```

As per Java doc of `java.util.PriorityQueue.PriorityQueue()`

```
Creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.
```

- **Q1)** Could any body please explain why the output is 1 3 2 and how
     the natural order works  here.
- **Q2)** I have checked about natural ordering and its related to the
     Comparable/Comparor but doesn't they are for
     Sorting(Ascending/Descending) Order only??

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/SDCebL)

Comment: Sorry! The initial sample was with `LinkedList`.Now updated the Java sample with `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 4):

The PriorityQueue in Java is a datastructure, that sorts the elements it contains. Excerpt from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

The Problem with the unordered output comes from the iterator implementation. Another excerpt, this time from the `iterator()` method:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

So you don't java a fixed order with the iterator. If you use the `poll()` method in a loop you would get all given elements in ascending order.

If you are looking for a Queue in the FIFO-sense you may have a look at the [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and only use the `addFirst()` and `getLast()` methods.

Comment: Little Weird! The `Iterator` returns the same order while traversing an `ArrayList` but for `PriorityQueue` it doesn't :(

Comment: Yep, very unintuitive. Another hint from the JavaDoc: You could use `Arrays.sort(q.toArray())` to have an ordered Array with the elements.

Comment: Just to Update here that even if you used `q.toArray()` that will return `Object[]` with natural order. So no need of extra `Arrays.sort` method here.

Comment: Guaranteed? The JavaDoc states `Returns an array containing all of the elements in this queue. The elements are in no particular order.` Maybe your values had the right order per "accident"?

Comment: Yes! I just performed following  test and traverse the Object array and its returning the elements in sorted manner `Object[] ob=(Object[]) q.toArray();
 for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++)
     System.out.println(ob[i]);`

Comment: hm, looks like it works for this example. Depending on the internal implementation this may change with other values or even with the same values on the same run. I doubt, that they forgot to update the JavaDoc. I would not count on the order of the toArray() method.